# ON DUPLICATE UPDATE - Does not work

Tags: php, mysql

There is my code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO item SET 
    player = '$player', 
    amount = '$amount', 
    item = '$item',
    allowed = '$allowed' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    amount = amount + $amount";
```

When I executing this query, in database creates new row despite the fact that it already      exists...

Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the key on your table?

Comment: What is your primary/unique key

Comment: There is no keys on table.

Comment: can you post the definition of table `item` and its keys. also, there seems to be a typo - extra *'* in your query: ` 'amount + $amount";`..

Comment: You must have unique key in the table.

Comment: If you don't have a key, the database won't know what a `DUPLICATE KEY` is.  You need a `UNIQUE KEY` on the field(s) you don't want duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments, you say there are no keys on the table.  That's a problem.  You're asking the database `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but without a `UNIQUE KEY`, it has no idea what a `DUPLICATE KEY` is.

You need to add a `UNIQUE KEY` (or a `PRIMARY KEY`) on the field(s) you don't want being duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is not correct, this corrected version:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO item SET 
    player = '$player', 
    amount = '$amount', 
    item = '$item',
    allowed = '$allowed' 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    amount = `amount` + '$amount' ";
```

Other factor depends on your table structure and the key

Comment: If `$amount` is an int, then the quotes don't matter.  Also, the backticks around `amount` don't really matter here either.

Comment: ok, you need to define key select the one that its a number and add unique index... or add primary key

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO DBNAME.item (player, amount, item, allowed) 
        values('$player', '$amount', '$item', '$allowed') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        amount = amount + values(amount);";
```

Comment: As long as he adds a `UNIQUE KEY` to the table :)

Comment: Why is that? Am i missing something? I believe he knows there must be primary or unique key ;)

Comment: In the comments on the question he says `There is [sic] no keys on table.`.  That's the issue here.  Without a key the database won't know what a `DUPLICATE KEY` is.  One he added a key, I assume his query would work.

Comment: Aw, I missed that comment, thanks for pointing it out +1 on comment.

Comment: Though, I like your SQL syntax better than the one he used.  I didn't know you could use `VALUES(amount)` like that!

Comment: [SOLVED] Thanks for all! I added unique key on table and query worked. Also I made VALUES(amount). Thanks for help.